# How to install GCC/c compiler inside of a Jenkins docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I currently have Jenkins running inside of a docker container (This is what Im using https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) and I am trying to build a Ruby On Rails CI workflow, but it doesnt seem like I can install Ruby because I get an error saying:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Whenever I attempt to build my Ruby On Rails project

How do you install GCC or another C compiler inside of a jenkins docker container?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *"install gcc in a docker container"*. The right way to do it is to create a derived container image from your Jenkins image. You create a `Dockerfile` with:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
USER jenkins
```

Then run:

```
docker build -t jenkins-gcc .
```

Now you have a `jenkins-gcc` image that you use instead of the `jenkins/jenkins` one.